# Issue to fire scroll events with Smooth Scrollbar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scroll, addeventlistener

I'm using the plugin Smooth Scrollbar ([here](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar)).

I have an animation on my fixed header (outside the smooth scrollbar container) and triggered when user starts scrolling the smooth scrollbar container. As mentioned in the documentation ([here](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/a35ec6fcef35d4363b4be7c08e2ce9db022953fa/docs/api.md#scrollbaraddlistener)), it's not possible that scrollbars fire scroll events. So we have to use:

```
 scrollbar.addListener((status) => {
   ...
 });
```

This is the code to animate my fixed header:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
     $('.site_header').removeClass('is--large').addClass('is--small');
   }
   else{
     $('.site_header').removeClass('is--small').addClass('is--large');
   }
 });
```

I can't figure it out how to integrate it with Smooth Scrollbar plugin. I tried various solutions to use addListener but I can't make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but:

```js
const scroller = document.querySelector('.scrollable');

const bodyScrollBar = Scrollbar.init(scroller, { damping: 0.1, delegateTo: window, alwaysShowTracks: false });

bodyScrollBar.addListener( () => {

   if (bodyScrollBar.scrollTop > 50){
     $('.site_header').removeClass('is--large').addClass('is--small');
   }
   else{
     $('.site_header').removeClass('is--small').addClass('is--large');
   }

  }
)
```

where .scroller is my scrolling container. Whenever you call the variable bodyScroller in the console you can see all options set and what value you can retrieve at any time. In this instance, by calling .scrollTop (NOT a function) you can retrieve its offset top value at any time.